# How do I set a environment variables in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to set several environment variables in Visual Studio code. Most of the instructions I've encountered are specifically for launch.json. However, I need to set these variables before the extension (project build extension) is started so it can access them.

The only way I can get the extension to see these variables is by setting them in a shell script before launching VS Code. This is unsatisfactory since the extension completely fails if you open VS code directly, or if you forget to execute the shell script.

Comment: set these environment variables in your shell startup script, or source a script on the command line and THEN call VSC from the same shell/command line. the variables need to be defined before the language server starts, and it starts when VSC starts

Comment: That really sucks!  How could they overlook this basic capability, yet support it for all kinds of other tasks?

Comment: the environment is set by the application/shell that launches an application. An application then reads the config files maybe from an environment setting, I have never come across an app that modifies its own environment for it own configuration. Fiond out if the language server has come settings you can change instead of using env vars

Comment: @rioV8  Most apps don't, but it is common if an app manages a toolchain. In my case, I want to set the vars before the extension loads. VSCode does allow you to set vars upon opening the folder, but it's well after the extension loads,